# how to add innerhtml to the specific ul of whose parent li is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add some content to ul class="overl" of whose parent li has been clicked and remove innerhtml of any previous li that was clicked?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testtab.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#chat ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
($(this).innerHTML="");

    //var i=$(this).closest('li').index();

    });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="chat" class="chat">
    <ul class="chatmenu">
        <li id="one" class="users"><a href="#one">abcy<span class="notify">1 new*</span></a>
            <div class="chattng">
                <ul class="overl">

                </ul>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li id="two" class="users"><a href="#two">avvv<span class="notify">a</span></a>
            <div class="chattng">
                <ul class="overl">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="three" class="users"><a href="#three">gtt<span class="notify">d</span></a>
        </li>
        <li id="four" class="users"><a href="#four">trt<span class="notify">e</span></a></li>
        <li id="five" class="users"><a href="#five">kkk<span class="notify">f</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </body>
 </html>
```

once it's known then how to do that whichever li is clicked it's innerhtml gets something and the previous li that was clicked has innerthtml as null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding `click` on `$(document).ready();`

Like

```
$(document).ready(
   function(){
     $('.overl').html("");
     $('#chat ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
       $(this).parent().children('.chattng').children('.overl').html("Your message");
   });
  });
```

Comment: I have edited my answer too... try the new answer.
Just added a line `$(this).parent().children('.chattng').children('.overl').html("Your message");`

Comment: I have edited my answer and added to clear `.overl`. Just added `$('.overl').html("");`.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up `DOM` methods and `jQuery` selectors:

```
$(this).innerHTML=""
```

Must be

```
 $(this).html("") // or $(this).empty()
```

Then, since you want to clear up your `li`, you'd want to do this :

```
$(this).parent().html("") // or $(this).parent().empty()
```